# How to Access resource Files inside WAR Using java from Wildfly 9

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-9

i have deployed WAR File to Wildfly 9 as [Zipped WAR][unexploded],so how can i access JSON resource files inside WAR.i tried many ways but not working.attached screenshot for reference. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HSJR.png)

Comment: There is no screen shot and this is a fairly broad question. Have a look at `Class.getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: Yes James,i will explain,i have JSON file in resource folder how can i access that file, kindly check attached screenshot now (Question corrected)

Comment: Again have a look at the [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).